# Can Solr be used with Coldfusion 8? Or is it better to just upgrade to 9?

Tags: coldfusion, solr

I have a client that wants to start using Solr instead of Verity, but they're running CF 8.

I'm thinking they would be better off upgrading to CF 9 then spending the time trying to get it to work on CF 8... I mean, they're going want to upgrade soon anyway.

What do you guys think? Anyone get it working on CF 8?

Comment: :) Upgrade it and save yourself the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can use it independently, and depending on the scale of your index, that may be a good idea even with CF9.  That is because you would easily have the option to run Solr on a dedicated machine as opposed to on the same machine as your CF server.  Just pick your favorite Java App Server (Tomcat, JBoss, etc...) and setup Solr on there.  You can then use the standard Solr webservices to make your queries and populate your index.